# Can't change Gnome 3 Themes in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I have recently installed the gnome 3 environment via the PPA. I installed the `gnome-themes-standard` package i believe, and now I can't use the tweak tool or `gconf` to change the theme because it is stuck on the current one. It seems to not want to change, I have no idea what I have done.

I am stuck at my current theme.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell`

Comment: Thanks Alvar! :D Works perfectly now :) I can't change themes graphically now, I need to change them via the file that the Gnome Shell uses to load themes, but atleast its working.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

http://gnome-look.org

If you want to change the appearance of your Gnome this is the right place for downloading new themes and stuff related to the Gnome look, they also provide support and how-to.

Comment: Hey Micro, I know where I can get themes. But the ones that I apply don't seem to do anything :/ I just did:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell

And now my theme has applied, this is really odd.

Comment: I added the answer that eorked for you. So others can be helped as well. @geissT